# what is the used technology on 3dvas.com

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d

I was wonder what is the technology that has been used to render the gallery on this 3d object

https://www.3dvas.com/galleries/gallery.php?r=1&ex=1489

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I wouldnt be able to tell the exact library *they* used to make their product (without seeing their source code), 3D Engines such as [Away3D](http://away3d.com/) are used to render such items in Flash and AIR products.

Comment: you made my day :)